# "She pulled back her fingers a second before they were sliced off." Does she still have all of her fingers?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I am reading a book (Hyperion, by Dan Simmons) and [the following phrase left](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hyperion/u4R_FstZDEgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22She%20pulled%20back%20her%20fingers%20a%20second%20before%20they%20were%20sliced%20off.%20%22&pg=PT282&printsec=frontcover) me flabbergasted!

> She pulled back her fingers a second before they were sliced off.

Does it mean that her fingers were sliced off a few seconds after she pulled them back? Or did she avoid that horrible fate by pulling them back?

How would one differentiate these two meanings (except by using the context)?

---

Edit: I did not provide the full passage because I wanted unbiased answers. The answers are satisfying, though, and the next part is:

> Rachel sat down in the darkness. An oscilloscope scraped against the ceiling until the table cracked and collapsed under it.

Comment: Aside from the ambiguity of the sentence, and how it could be rephrased, doesn't the book actually answer the question shortly afterwards, one way or the other? (I can also see the author using the ambiguity *intentionally* in order to build up suspense.) Or is the fate of her fingers left in doubt up until the last word?

Comment: He withdrew his application shortly before it was rejected. So, the application was in [send in to the appropriate "authorities"]. So.....now what?

Comment: Reminder to everyone: Don't answer in comments. If you have an answer, leave it as an answer :)

Comment: @V2Blast: If you start pulling at that thread, this whole site could unravel.

Comment: Why are so many people having a conniption?  This is *fiction*, and the rhythm of the words is as important as the literal meaning.  Yes, there are a dozen ways to make it less ambiguous, but probably few of them would maintain the author's characteristic rhythm.

Comment: To confirm or not whether the ambiguity is intentional, could you provide a sentence or two either side of the example sentence?

Comment: "I did not specify the next part, because I wanted unbiased answers." Unbiased inference: The author never said what were sliced off -- not her fingers, obviously.

Comment: This sounds like the author might be the Dan Brown of SciFi.

Comment: @anongoodnurse, impossible. We're not told the brand of the oscilloscope, and there isn't a single adjective in the quoted text. Besides, the Dan Brown of SciFi is Dan Brown. If you haven't read *Digital Fortress*, don't.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Oh no... He branched out? "If you haven't read Digital Fortress, don't." Lol, no worries there! (And there's no incomprehensible metaphor in the sentence, either, e.g. 'She pulled back her fingers a second before they were sliced off like a watermelon on a spike.')

Comment: This made for a surprising Hot Network Question title coming from EnglishSE

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The one thing that seems to be agreed by the answers so far is that the intended meaning is obvious:  she pulled back her hand  seconds before her fingers (to use questioner’s own word) **could** be sliced off.

The word *could* in this context has counterfactual force.

It has been pointed out that the same grammatical structure can transform the semantics by the substitution of the word *head* for the word *fingers*.  So there is a grammatical ambiguity.  And it could be avoided by the substitution of the subjunctive *could*.

But wait a minute.  Here is another example.  A parent shouts at her/his child, shivering in an icy lake:

> Get out of the water before you die of cold!

Nobody will imagine that the parent intends the child to get out of the water **and then** die of cold.  Clearly there is a well-established ***preventative*** usage of *before* in addition to the temporal one.

So should the writer go the extra mile and prevent any possible ambiguity by inserting *could*?

No.  The whole point of the situation is surely to emphasise **how close** she came to losing her fingers.  That is done by using the original words and so rendering the tense moment as vivid as possible.

So the sentence is **grammatically** ambiguous but **contextually** clear and **in literary terms** justified.

Comment: TL;DR: *colloquial*, +1. OP is ESL if I had to guess. I had to read the sentence a few times to even understand their perspective.

Comment: Best and most sensible answer: I upvotes!

Comment: This is correct, as it is is simply the use of "before" with the meaning "In preference to" or "rather than" an accepted definition in any dictionary (google it).

Comment: +1. Though "before they **would have been** sliced off" sounds more typical that "**could**".

Comment: "...in literary terms justified." Are you sure? I know of no source that justifies bad writing. This is an example of just plain bad writing.

Comment: I am offering an opinion.  You may, of course, disagree.  I do not say it is good or excellent writing.  You would need to see far more of the text to say anything like that.  All I am saying is that strict rules of grammar and semantics may be stretched for literary reasons.  Absolute absence of ambiguity is a core rule for expository writing.  For connotative (literary) writing it is not.

Comment: Stop in the name of love lest you break my heart. Lest you accuse me take a look at yourself. Etc. Doesn't sound quite as... current, I suppose.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the additional question about what the author "should" do.  This is purely opinion based, a value judgement. It isn't our purpose to tell authors how they should write, but to simply to explain what the common and acceptable practices are. It would be better to describe the effect and how it is different from the prescriptively correct version, rather than to specify that one or the other is better.

Comment: @trlkly: to be fair, I did not ask about what the author should do, but how one (or me) would differenciate the two meaning. And yes I am ESL :)

Comment: @anongoodnurse You need to define the phrase "bad writing." If you're saying quality fiction cannot use incorrect grammar, Shakespeare, Twain, Faulkner and Baldwin would tend to disagree.

Comment: I disagree with the 'die of cold' comparison. The original post was past progressive. "Were sliced" sounds like an action completed in the past, while "die" is present tense... "before you die" is a forecast. "before they were sliced off" could be serializing the order of events in the past. "I told her to get out of the water before she was dead from cold." Is more in line with the ambiguous mess of the OP. :)

Comment: @barbecue - This writer is no  Shakespeare, Twain, or Faulkner. Not all writing is good writing. This isn't this decade's *Ulysses*.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I don’t think anyone has suggested that the writing is of particularly good quality.  All I said was that you could justify a degree of ambiguity on the basis of literary effect.  The literary standing of the author or what s/he has written is not at stake here.

Comment: Polite request.  I am most grateful to those who have been giving me all these points.  But please now stop.  What I wrote was, I hope, helpful.  But it is getting more points than it can possibly deserve.

Comment: @Tuffy - That is the nature of a Hot Network Question. It happens to many of us. No modesty required, and certainly not a plea for fewer votes. And of course the position that this is bad writing has been challenged.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I didn't make any statement about the quality of this particular writer. I merely pointed out the fact that "bad writing" does not mean the same thing as "ambiguous grammar." The list of reasons why fiction writing does not need to follow strict rules of grammar is far too long to discuss here.

Comment: @Mazura Maybe, but that statement reveals as much about you as about the OP (as communication always does). I, a native speaker, got it nearly immediately, but then I enjoy such puzzles.

Comment: The cure for an out-of-control HNQ is to make it a CW.  That's up to you.

Answer (score 32):

The sentence is grammatically ambiguous, and you have to use common sense about the situation and intent to disambiguate it. If it had been:

> She begged for mercy a few seconds before her fingers were sliced off.

it would be clear that she no longer has her fingers and the begging simply preceded the slicing.

But in the given sentence, there doesn't seem to be any reason to mention pulling back her fingers unless this action prevented the slicing.

Comment: I can imagine situations where you would mention pulling back fingers even if they were sliced off, but I would express such an occurrence with words like "tried" or "although" to emphasize that she was unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I thought about adding another case like "Her fingers shook before ..."

Comment: Good example, nevertheless if it had been: `She **successfully** begged for mercy a few seconds before her fingers were sliced off.` then I would understand that she kept her fingers. The meaning (and fingers) comes and goes! It's a really subtly ambiguous sentence!

Comment: @xDaizu Or perhaps the "mercy" was that she lost her fingers rather than her whole arm.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Then you'd expect it to say "before *only* her fingers were cut off." The point of all this is that there's much more to writing understandably than just proper grammar.

Comment: @xDaizu I would interpret your statement as, "she managed to say utter the words before it happened," not, "she managed to prevent it from happening." In other words, I would understand that statement to be sarcastic in any sense broader than its literal meaning.

Answer (score 17):

> "She pulled back her fingers a second before they were sliced off."

So, does she still have her fingers? The sentence could use disambiguation.

*disambiguate* [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/disambiguation)

> To establish a single grammatical or semantic interpretation for

As in:

> "She pulled back her fingers a second before they **would have been**
>   sliced off."

or

> "She pulled back her fingers a second late and they were sliced off."

Likely this question is from a sentence in Dan Simmons book **Hyperion** [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=u4R_FstZDEgC&lpg=PT317&dq=%22She%20pulled%20back%20her%20fingers%20a%20second%20before%20they%20were%20sliced%20off%22&pg=PT318#v=onepage&q=%22She%20pulled%20back%20her%20fingers%20a%20second%20before%20they%20were%20sliced%20off%22&f=false). It's SciFi.  The paragraphs following the sentence are
unrevealing as to the fate of the fingers.  I have not read the book. Indeed it is an ambiguous sentence. Poetic license!

Comment: This is my favourite wording. "Would have been" is what I immediately jumped to as the unambiguous, "correct" phrasing

Comment: Yes, IBF, ‘poetic licence’ is the phrase. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the logic is correct, she did not lose her fingers.

What I mean to say, is that, logically speaking, if her fingers are not in the place where they are to be cut off a very short time before the action would happen, then she will not lose her fingers.

So, semantically speaking, if you qualify an action with a precise point in time (in this case, her fingers getting cut off), and she performs some action in the second before that removes her fingers from the place where this action is supposed to occur, the slicing occurs, however, with the fingers absent from the slicing time and place, they are not cut off. Had she left her fingers, they would have been cut off.

I think the sentence is confusing in the first sense of instinct of reading it like the action occurred even though she pulled her fingers away, but I think what is actually happening is that the action is being linked to a point in time and so what is being referenced by name is not the action of her losing her fingers, but the point in time where she would have lost her fingers.

Comment: I agree that there is a strong inference that she avoided injury, but it is not at all clear. Suppose her fingers were originally in a position that they would be completely (or perhaps mostly) sliced off. At the last moment, "She pulled back her fingers a second before they were sliced off". Pulling her fingers back does not insure or indicate that she didn't suffer any injury in the process ... perhaps half of each finger was sliced off.

Comment: @KevinFegan I really doubt that. That would be reading too far into it. As Tuffy's excellent answer above indicates, there is a (strongly implied and likely true) sense of prevention of an action with the usage of *before* in this case.

Comment: @psouna If you wish to interpret the sentence strictly, based solely on what is explicit, would it not mean that she moved her fingers some distance before something else happened to them, namely, getting cut off? There's no explicit mention in this statement that she moved them far enough, or even that the cutting was bound to a specific location. Perhaps the cutting device was portable, and attached to her hand the entire time.

Comment: @jpaugh It could very well be -- but that's not what we can gather out of what is being said. I also am not saying that what I'm saying is 100% factual, either; it could easily be that the fingers get cut off anyway. The thing I'm saying is that, if you speak of an action as a point in time, and another second preventative action as a separate point in time, and the preventative action happens *before* the first action, the first action gets negated as a result of the impossibility of the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Your intriguing situation is covered by **literary license** as noted in the last line of @lbf's answer. According to Wikipedia,

> Artistic license (also known as art license, historical license, dramatic license, poetic license, narrative license, licentia poetica, creative license, or simply license) is a colloquial term, sometimes a euphemism, used to denote the distortion of fact, alteration of the conventions of grammar or language, or rewording of pre-existing text made by an artist in the name of art.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license

The operative concept here is

> alteration of the conventions of grammar or language

and the meaning is established by context. But the way you found it written,

> she pulled back her fingers a second before they were sliced off

makes the meaning extremely clear and unequivocal to habitual readers of English (that her fingers ***just escaped*** being sliced off) although the most unambiguous and "correct" way of writing it would be

> She pulled back her fingers a second before they **could be** sliced off

where "before + could" clearly establishes that the event did not occur, as rightly pointed out in the earlier excellent answer of @Tuffy.

But [authors don't care](https://www.google.com/search?q=honey+badger+dont+care).

Moreover, this type of usage with "before" being used to describe *just avoiding something happening* is a well established convention of its own in both the spoken and the written language, as the other answers already attest; random examples:

> The rope pulled him up just inches before his head hit the ground (as in bungee jumping)
>
> They managed to save their marriage before it collapsed
>
> Get in out of the rain before you catch a cold.

Comment: In the broadest sense of language uses (i.e, not to do with authoring books), this has little to do with artistic license. Such ambiguous phrases are used in every day situations because they're shorter or easier to write/say than many unambiguous phrases.

Comment: Yes; and not even considered ambiguous by most readers @jpaugh.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the book, IIRC, the sentence is very unambiguous. She pulled back her fingers and they were *indeed* sliced off a second later. This is science fiction and part of this series contains a character called the The Shrike (capitals intentional). The following text is taken from the wikipedia entry about the [Hyperion Cantos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_Cantos#The_Shrike)

**SPOILER ALERT**

> The region of the Tombs is also the home of the Shrike, a menacing half-mechanical, half-organic four armed creature that features prominently in the series ...  It is portrayed as composed of razorwire, thorns, blades, and cutting edges, having fingers like scalpels and long, curved toe blades. It has the ability to control the flow of time, and may thus appear to travel infinitely fast. The Shrike may kill victims in a flash or it may transport them to an eternity of impalement

You may not have gotten to the point yet in the book or series where this explained in more detail. It is part of the mystery.

Comment: After reading this answer, I don't see how the information in it establishes that the fingers were indeed sliced off.

Comment: @sumelic Major spoiler alert: it is more than twenty years ago that I read the book. Rereading the relevant passages (from google books as I don't own a copy) the loss of her fingers is a minor detail as she is subsequently encased in an anti-entropic field whose persistent after effect is that she becomes physically and mentally one day younger every day. She herself has no recollection of the event as she loses one day of memory every day as well. It is plausible that the anti-entropic field causes her physical state to be reset as well. You can read the sentence as is, no ambiguity.

Comment: I thought the sentence was perfectly unambiguous in the other direction, as one can't logically pull back their fingers before they are sliced off and then also have them sliced off.  Though if anyone could do it, it would be the Shrike with its disrespect for time.  However, if I recall, in that scene, weren't her fingers nearly removed by the door to the room being obscured by the closing walls, not the Shrike?

Comment: @Tofystedeth It was the ceiling coming down over a corridor shaft and you may be correct. Yet the Shrike is present in the room closing in on her as borne out in the next paragraph. I read the sentence as is, thinking that the author would have written "She pulled back her fingers a second before they would have been sliced off." as stated in another answer.

Comment: @GretchenV I think your answer, if slightly reworded, is useful for establishing that the meaning cannot be assumed unambiguous in the other direction; but it doesn't establish unambiguity in this direction, either. (I've never read the book, so I'm relying on your answer & comments alone to convince me.)

Answer (score 1):

Just a note that this is known in the trade as "[Counterfactual *before*](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ecleoc/semfest09.pdf)", as in

- *Get him out of here before the Dean sees him.*
- *We got him out before the Dean could see him.* (the Dean didn't see him)
- *We got him out before the Dean saw him.* (ambiguous; maybe the Dean saw him, after)

The first one is an order, but it still has counterfactual force.

The second one is what comes to mind to avoid ambiguity, skewering it with a modal inside the counterfactual scope ("not possible" instead of "possible not").

The third one leaves it open whether the Dean saw him (because no overt modal, though it's invited strongly). If it's true, any such seeing event took place after we got him out.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities: (1) a careful writer and (2) a sloppy writer and editor.

In (1) the fingers were sliced off.  **That is what the sentence says.**  The unfortunate lady pulled her fingers back, but a skillful slicer-offer compensated for the pullback and advanced his slice.  It wasn't as neat and as even and as clean a slice, but goodbye fingers.  (Analogy:  The tennis ball jumped to the side before she hit it. The player compensated for the jump.)

In (2) the writer and editor were sloppy.  Other answers told us the correct wording if the lady kept her fingers.  Only the subsequent sentences can tell us whether (1) or (2) is correct.

Comment: I was about to write something similar. I suspect that the only butchery occurring in the sample sentence is in how it is written. This sentence, severed from the rest of the story, tells us that the fingers were cleaved. A dissection of the whole story should have revealed that, leaving no one aghast by such a barbaric choice of words. But I suspect that was not the case.

Comment: It's only "sloppy" if it's being submitted to an academic journal. No experienced reader is going to be confused by this. -1

Comment: @jpmc26 - If you said that just before your head was removed, would you be in the mood to tell us how that turned out for you? :)

Comment: @CanisLupus No, but if I pulled my head down just before it was removed, I would. I agree with the answers that it *could* be disambiguated, but calling it "sloppy" is far too harsh a judgement. The disambiguated version is a lot wordier and doesn't read as smoothly, so it is at worst a stylistic choice.

Comment: I  think that the phrase: "a second before" actually saves the day.

Comment: @jpmc26 I can't testify to experience, but readers of this sentence [have disagreed](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/443208/10120) in this thread.